# How to solve error "EAI_NONAME - Neither nodename nor servname provided, or not known"?

Tags: filezilla

I've tried to connect to a server quite a few different ways, but since it's my first time trying to use FileZilla I'm having a really hard time. When I try to connect with site manager using ftp, I get this error message:

Status: Resolving address of stackoverflowliam.net 
Status: Connection attempt failed with "EAI_NONAME - Neither nodename nor servname provided, or not known". 
Error:  Could not connect to server

I've tried changing the server name quite a few times, adding ftp, www, url, and a few other three letter combinations before the url name.

Does anyone have any clue what's going on? I know there are similar questions out there, but the only solution I've found is to remove the "ftp." from the beginning of the file name, which I don't have.